# php SELECT query works with value but not with variable

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to select a column from a table named say, `1234`.

```
      $query="select Number from `$table`";
      $contacts=mysql_query($query);

      while($row=mysql_fetch_array($contacts))
         echo $row['Number'];
```

If I use "select Number from `1234`", it works. The value for $table is got using $_REQUEST["key0"]. I call the page as `"localhost/page_id=22?key0=1234"` What's the problem? I get the following error at mysql_fetch_array statement : `Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\wp-content\plugins\exec-php\includes\runtime.php(42)`

Comment: Did you echo out the value of `$table`? Also, please do read up on SQL injection. The way you create queries is very unsafe - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/xkcd-sql-injection-please-explain.

Comment: I tried to echo it too. It doesn't even print the value.

Comment: That mean you don't have the value. If it's not printing then the value is not populated. Also, if you're getting that error it means that your mysql_connect call didn't finish properly

Comment: Hello What is the Page_id? is it the argument?

Comment: you're going to get hacked.  this code is a very bad idea.  start with PDO, get rid of the table name in the URL - what happens when that is changed to another table name?  What happens when someone types in other sql commands for the table name?  this is insanity.

Comment: hm, `page_id=22?key0=1234`... you really don't see anything wrong here??? you can't have `page_id=22` as page name!

Comment: @zander, show us more code... mysql_connect() and so on

Comment: @Wh1T3h4Ck5 Well My wordpress had some problem. It works in plain php. Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The url you call should be formatted like this:

```
localhost/?page_id=22&key0=1234
```

Also, `1234` is a weird name for a table :))

Comment: Thanks for that. Now, echoing $table works. But the warning still remains and the query doenst get executed.

Comment: Check that both `Number` [with uppercase N!] field and `1234` table exist in your db. Try to run the query in you mysql client of choice / phpmyadmin to read the sql error.

Answer (score 0):

Write it like this `"select Number from ".$table;`

Comment: Nope  That doesn't work either

Comment: See if the value in $table is correct or not.

Answer (score 0):

`$contacts` is what was returned from your query, it will return false if u have some type of error.
So:

1. Catch the error (read on try-catch)
2. You probably do not have a table called 1234. In the FROM clause u must use existing elements/table from your DB (or temp tables generated from such)
3. Good luck with SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

```
$conn=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("as you wish",$conn);  
$query="select Number from `$table`";
      $contacts=mysql_query($query,$conn);

      while($row=mysql_fetch_array($contacts))
         echo $row['Number'];
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

This is going to work for sure.

```
 "SELECT * 
    FROM  `yourdatabase_name`.`$table` "
```

Comment: explain, why you're so sure? It works if database wasn't previously selected but this doesn't look as obvious reason for issue. One thing is sure, this fixes unselected database issue, nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use something like this

**localhost/?page_id=22&key0=1234**  but in your question you mention you are using localhost/page_id=22?key0=1234 so just try as i mention here!

hope it will help you